# Seeking site(s) to ask questions about metric units and spelling

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation, migration, multiple-questions

On October 16, 2019, I asked the question [Why is the ångström not a metric unit? And why is the ångström spelled with the Swedish/Finnish letters "å" and "ö"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508572/) on the Physics site. It has got useful answers. However, my question is downvoted to -5. I asked a question about metric units and about spelling, neither of which are suitable on the Physics site.
What is the correct site where I can ask a question about metric units? And what is the correct site where I can ask a question about the spelling? How do I rephrase both my questions?

Comment: [hsm.se] allows questions about [units](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units), but I can't guarantee your question is acceptable or not. Consider asking on their child meta.

Comment: Why is your question written twice within the body of this question?

Comment: @PolyGeo Because i need to ask for two correct sites.

Comment: @PolyGeo: They are not identical ("metric units" vs. "spelling", etc.)

Comment: A wall of text is not an improvement.

Comment: I missed the slight difference between the two questions which could have been made more obvious by bolding that bit. In any event I think it is always best to ask only one question per question.

Comment: More context for why this question is here: From comments on that Physics Meta question: *"Questions about where to ask questions are likely better asked on meta.stackexchange.com/questions"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, you’re asking two separate questions. One about the usage of the unit and the other about the spelling.

Stack Exchange typically wants questioners to stick with one question per question.

So, separate the questions and ask them on the relevant sites. Or look on Wikipedia, which is generally very good on the sciences; experts on the science SE sites generally expect some level of research before someone asks a question - questions that are easily answered from Google or Wikipedia can be downvoted accordingly.

Bonus: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angstrom

(The spelling is that way because it’s named after [the Swedish physicist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Jonas_%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m).)